# Keeping line weight the same when resizing images in PIL/Pillow?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I'm using Pillow/PIL in Python 3.x to make some Chinese-like characters composed out of other characters and radicals. These are made from taking in 2 100x100px images from 2 different folders, and then have one of the images stretched/resized to fit one of 12 templates. The character is then output as a 100x100px image. This process is done for about 750 characters total.

However, the character set I'm basing this on is an [East Asian Gothic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_Gothic_typeface) font, where each line stroke is of constant width (mostly).

Because of how Pillow resizes images, the stroke widths are also changed. For example, I have a character that is composed of the two characters below:

[image]

The left character is placed and stretched so that it is on the left side of the right character. My current code gives the below for these two specific characters:

[image]

[image]

Note how the left character's vertical stroke is thinner than the right character's.
This is consistent with all characters, with horizontal strokes also:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way in Pillow/PIL to preserve the stroke width like this? Are there any alternatives that can do this? Do remember that there are 750 characters that need to be adjusted; doing so manually is impractical.

Comment: I suggest using a vector graphics system rather than bitmaps, but that may be a bit late if you've already built 750 characters. But anyway, you can do this directly in [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), or you could work at a higher level, using a library like Cairo.

Comment: From what I understood (rectify if i am wrong), you are trying to resize the image (having a character in it) after which the size of the character also gets changed. And what you want is to increase the size of the image without changing the size of the character.

Comment: Could you be clearer about **how** you place and resize the characters please? And show your code and inputs and outputs. To my Western eye, I can't even see a problem with your last two examples!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm currently away from my computer so I don't have the code, but the gist of it is that I set the top-left and bottom-right corners of the character (this case the left) based on the other character. I then paste the now-resized left side to where the character should be. I'll also add in an image to show how the pixel count changes.

Comment: I think you are looking for *"seam carving"* a.k.a. *"liquid rescaling"*... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving If I can get a better handle on what you have and what you want I may be able to help further. At the moment it's all a hit vague.